# using json data from ajax call in rendering html elements in datatables

Tags: datatables

I'm using [Ajax data source (objects)](https://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html) for rendering datatables. 
here is the example json:

```
"data": [{
    "news_id": 22,
    "news_title": "Annual function held in school",
    "news_details": "Annual function was held in school",
    "created_at": "2016-02-19 17:01:38",
    "imgurl": "uploads/images/8.JPG"
}]
```

now, using last element `"imgurl"`, I want to render a link in the last column of the datatables. like this one:[uploads/images/8.JPG](http://www.example.com/uploads/images/8.JPG).
I tried rendering a custom column as follows:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": '?r=news/ajaxdata',
        "columns": [
            { "data": "news_id" },
            { "data": "news_title" },
            { "data": "news_details" },
            { "data": "created_at" },
            { "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
            return $('<a>')
                        .attr('href', {"data": "imgurl"})
                        .text('link')
                        .wrap('<div></div>')
                        .parent()
                        .html();
    } },

        ]
    } );
```

It does not seem to be a proper way to do as it renders a link but the href element says [object][object]. I couldn't find the right documentation to do this either. can anybody help?

tried this:

```
{ "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                var d = JSON.parse(data);
                var d = d.imgurl; 
            return $('<a>')
                        .attr('href', d)
                        .text('link')
                        .wrap('<div></div>')
                        .parent()
                        .html();

    } },
```

the problem is to handle the ajax response.

Comment: Just hit this. It seems the datatables render function will accept only a string return, and that is treated as raw HTML. However, that is not even documented. I am surprised it will not accept a DOM element without rendering it as "[object]". I have a feeling, given the examples published everywhere, there is much incorrect HTML escaping nightmares out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First argument `data` holds data for the cell so it will have image URL `uploads/images/8.JPG`.

Use the code below instead:

```js
{ 
    data: 'imgurl', //<----
    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
        return 
           $('<a>')
              .attr('href', data)
              .text('link')
              .wrap('<div></div>')
              .parent()
              .html();
   } 
},
```

See [`columns.render`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) for more information.

Comment: but  I want to use only the "data":"imgurl" part of the ajax response. this does not work.

Comment: @RameshPareek - have updated gyrocodes answer, he just forgot the important `data`-reference (how should dataTables know which `data` to pass, if `data` not is set?) - guess he focused on the `render` part because it is so obvious that you have to define `data` too. Hope it helps. I think gyrocode have answered correct despite this little confusion.

Comment: @davidkonrad, yes. but I figured it out as he referred me to the right documentation. :) thanks.